# Placeholder on java Scanner

Tags: java

In console how can I have a placeholder on my scanner?

Let me show you an example

```
public class main {
  string name;
  public void main(){
   name = " default ";
  }

 public void modif(){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String str = sc.nextLine(); // At this moment i want in the console the current value of name. The user can delete it, and replace it with the new name. Or just modify it
  this.name=str;
 }
}
```

Thanks a lot to read me and sorry for my English.

Comment: You cannot do it in console application. For text editing you need to build some UI.

Comment: If you are not limited to console then you can use something like `String str = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter new name", name); if (str!=null) this.name = str;`

Comment: My Question is which part of code is calling `modif()` method

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do in console that often looks good: print out the default value

```
> Enter your name (jonny):
```

If the user enters nothing and just hits `Enter`, use the default.

If the user does enter something, use that.

Answer (score -1):

This is easy with just a small trick

and trick is `System.out.print("Enter Name: ");`. Use `print` method for placeholder not `println`.

This is the complete main method.

```
public static void main(String... string) {

        Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: That would not place default value of name in console so it would end in `System.in` without user needing to write it (which seems to be what OP wants).